# Find a group of rotation of a cube

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a group of rotation of a cube.

Could someone tell me how we are looking for it. For square i can do it but for cube i dont want how start. I know group of cube has 24 elements.

Rotation what we have is I,90,180,270 right?

Comment: What if you rotate the cube through an axis joining two opposite corners?

Comment: So we are rotate the cube over 6 axis using all rotation? like h - vertical axis (h,I),(v,90) etc?